# Strange behavior in C when comparing integers

Tags: c, clang

This problem is encountered in my mac environment where the gcc version is shown below:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

The code segment is from one of the function.

```
int someFunction(int x, int n) {
    int TMin_n = -(1 << (n-1));
    int TMax_n = (1 << (n-1)) - 1;
    int a = -2147483648;
    printf("%s\n", x == a ? "true" : "false");      // true
    printf("%s\n", x <= TMax_n ? "true" : "false"); // false
    printf("%s\n", a <= TMax_n ? "true" : "false"); // true
    printf("%d %d %d\n", TMin_n, x, TMax_n);        // -2147483648 -2147483648 2147483647
    return 0;
}
```

a is equal to x, but why they have different behavior when comparing to TMax_n?

**UPDATE**:

all the data types in this code segment is `int`.

**UPDATE2**:

Thanks everyone. I just tried the same code on an ubuntu machine and that works fine. It only stuck on my MAC.Seems that it is a problem related with the compiler.

Comment: What is `x` or `TMax_n`? Your example is not **complete**. See [mcve].

Comment: It is not GCC, it is clang (default compiler on MacOS since - well, a while now...).

Comment: What are the types of TMax_n and TMin_n? Are they perhaps unsigned? Do you know the rules when operators deal with types of different signedness?

Comment: Still after your edit, you do not show the type of x - the only meaningful explanation for this behaviour is x being *unsigned*...

Comment: By the way, are you aware that there are already appropriate constants defined in <limits.h> (INT_MIN and INT_MAX)?

Comment: Yes, this is actually a test. I was just playing with shifting. And this strange behavior come to me.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; at least with `n=32`, I get 3 x `true`.

Comment: @xidui I wasn't one, but the downvote(s) would have been because the original question contained incomplete information that was vital if an answer was to be given (and as of writing at least one has been reversed). FWIW, the code above (called with `someFunction( -2147483648, 32 ) ;` works fine on VS2008 but gives the results you see if you change `x` to `unsigned`.

Comment: Same for me, cannot reproduce, using mingw64 on windows currently. Might check at home, too, GCC 5.x under linux, but don't expect a different result...

Comment: Is this 100% copy/pasted problematic code? I.e. it's not `i32 someFunction(i32 x, i32 n)` with some custom type typedefs, which are accidentally unsigned?

Comment: Side note: We would get the same result (apart from the numbers printed out) for any negative number, if x was unsigned: `int a = <any negative number>; unsigned int x = a; [...]`...

Comment: @Groo yeah, that's the exact same code that was stuck. And the same code worked fine on another environment.

Comment: Would be curious on your Mac now - sure, this is C, but what, if you tried the same with C++? Exactly your code as you have, but add one additional line after last printf: `std::cout << TMin_n << ' ' << x << ' ' << TMax_n << std::endl;`. My point is: The correct operator is now selected via type resolution - if there goes something wrong with your types, then you should see immediately...

Comment: @Aconcagua I tried with C++ in Xcode, this problem disappeared.

Comment: @xidui Interesting. Sure, C and C++ are not the same, but in this case, they should behave exactly the same. I consider this as another hint to a compiler bug just as Groo's answer already...

Comment: `1 << (n-1)` is undefined behavior for 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be due to undefined behaviour within expression `(1 << (n-1)) - 1`, particularly in `(1 << (n-1))`, as `1` is treated as an `int` (probably 32 bit), and expression `(1 << (n-1))` then yields a value which is one above the maximum value representable by an  `int`. So this (intermediate) result leads to a signed integer arithmetic overflow, which is UB (cf. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic)):

> When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does
>   not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined: it may wrap
>   around according to the rules of the representation (typically 2's
>   complement), it may trap on some platforms or due to compiler options
>   (e.g. -ftrapv in GCC and Clang), or may be completely optimized out by
>   the compiler.

So it may work on some compilers, it may not work on others. 
However, if you cast to `unsigned int` before bitshift, the overflow goes away and you are back in defined (and expected) behaviour:

```
(int) (((unsigned)1 << (n-1)) - 1)
```

BTW: if you set `-ftrapv` in the "other compiler options" for the C-compiler, then the expressions `int TMin_n = -(1 << (n-1))` and `int TMax_n = (1 << (n-1)) - 1` lead to a runtime exception (e.g. `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`).

Comment: +1 Yes, you're correct, thanks for a better explanation and the suggestion for `-ftrapv` (although it's not a compiler error, but a trap IMHO?). I thought it was a compiler issue and didn't even realize the value. Casting the `0x80000000` part to `(long long)` and then the result back to `int` would also do the trick. `a = -2147483648` is also UB.

Comment: Alternative: using 1u?  `int max = (1U << (n-1)) - 1` looks much nicer to me. Any reason for explicit cast?

Answer (score 3):

I tried your snippet using an [online clang compiler](http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_clang) and got the results from the question. I am presuming the code (including the function call) gets completely inlined, and then the compiler optimizes away all comparisons it finds constant.

The line in question seems to be:

```
int TMax_n = (1 << (n-1)) - 1;
```

If I explicitly cast `(1 << (n-1))` to `unsigned`, the issue goes away:

```
int TMax_n = (int) ((unsigned)(1 << (n-1)) - 1);
```

Comment: Very interesting - but this really looks like a compiler bug to me then!

Comment: @Aconcagua: Actually not a compiler bug, but UB. See answer below.

Comment: @StephanLechner Very true - oversaw that completely. Good eye of yours... Would have disrupted my so far good impression of clang, if it really was a bug...